# How to port a DLL access code from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, unmanaged

I'm trying to get the FPS data from "Fraps". There is a project called LCDHost on github which has done this. Apparently it's done by hooking to "fraps.dll"

I need to port this code to a C# project i'm working on. Problem is I'm not good at C++ and haven't got any experience in accessing unmanaged dlls from C#.

If someone can give me pointers on how to convert this code to C#, I'd appreciate that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include "LH_Text.h"

struct FRAPS_SHARED_DATA {
   DWORD sizeOfStruct;
   DWORD currentFPS;
   DWORD totalFrames;
   DWORD timeOfLastFrame;
   char gameName[32];
};

FRAPS_SHARED_DATA *(WINAPI *FrapsSharedData) ();    
int notify(int n,void* p)
{
    if( !n || n&LH_NOTE_SECOND )
    {
        HMODULE frapsDLL;
        FRAPS_SHARED_DATA *fsd;
        frapsDLL = GetModuleHandleA("FRAPS32.DLL");
        if (!frapsDLL) {
            if( setText("N/A") ) callback(lh_cb_render,NULL);
        } else {
            FrapsSharedData = (typeof(FrapsSharedData)) GetProcAddress(frapsDLL, "FrapsSharedData");
            if (!FrapsSharedData) {
                if( setText("Needs Fraps 1.9C or later!") ) callback(lh_cb_render,NULL);
            } else {
                if( setText( "Fraps is running & is the right version." ) ) callback(lh_cb_render,NULL);
                fsd = FrapsSharedData();
                if( setText(QString::number(fsd->currentFPS) ) ) callback(lh_cb_render,NULL);
            }
        }
    }
    return LH_Text::notify(n,p) | LH_NOTE_SECOND;
}
```

The line that really stumped me is this one

```
FrapsSharedData = (typeof(FrapsSharedData)) GetProcAddress(frapsDLL, "FrapsSharedData");
```

I don't know what's the equivalent of it in C#

The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/linkdata/LCDHost/blob/18108e259bae5b30d0fd965cf1092471ecff6b69/plugins/LH_Text/LH_TextFraps.cpp)

Comment: The C++ code is loading the DLL at runtime.  All GetProcAddress does is get a pointer to the DLL function it wants to call later on.  This is all C++ stuff that you shouldn't worry about In C# -- just read up on how to interface to a third-party DLL in C# -- that is the very first step.

Comment: Usually can achieve this  with the `DllImport` Attribute Class , https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202744/dynamically-p-invoking-a-dll?  There are a couple of useful links there to articles on how to do LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress in C#

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie:  I think he very much does have to worry about this in C# - the call must not be made if the current installed DLL is an old version.  MDK: I don't think `DllImport` will help (much) for the same reason.

Comment: @MartinBonner I disagree.  The OP's Question seems to indicate trying to understand dynamic binding to DLL.  Although it was used in version qualification I dont believe thats what the OP needs to understand

Comment: @MartinBonner: If you check the actual code behavior, not the strings, it simply says that the function pointer should not be used if it is null.  P/invoke will catch that case (missing export) as well and throw it as an exception which can be handled in C#.

Comment: FrapsSharedData is a function pointer declaration, the exact equivalent in C# is a delegate.  The cast on the GetProcAddress() return value needs to be Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer() and a cast to the delegate type.

Comment: There seems to be an awful lot of pointers in C++, is it just my untrained eye or do they make code very hard to read?
'FRAPS_SHARED_DATA *(WINAPI *FrapsSharedData) ();   '
What does that even mean?

Comment: No, they don't make things hard to read (unless you have too many at once).  FrapsSharedData is a pointer to a function which takes no arguments, uses the WINAPI calling convention, and returns a pointer to a FRAPS_SHARED_DATA structure.

Comment: @MartinBonner I tried to make this work as standalone C++ application. Figured that I could output the value from it to C#._
  FrapsSharedData = (typeid(FrapsSharedData).name()) GetProcAddress(frapsDLL, "FrapsSharedData");_
This line still gives error. The error message is " 3 IntelliSense: a value of type "const char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "FRAPS_SHARED_DATA *(__stdcall *)()"ConsoleApplication1.cpp 33 19 ConsoleApplication1
"

Answer (score 3):

Use DllImport Attribute and it will call an unmanaged dlls. Just find the necessary C library call an appropriate function from it.
Very useful example is there:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but the link you provided seems be be about C++. I've found  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450783/how-to-use-dllimport-in-c) post. Might be related to my case

Comment: That what I was talking about. It doesn't matter. It works for C++ and Sharp. But in DllImport attribute put DLL needed for you.

Comment: Managed to get the pointer to the struct from the DLL. Can't figure out how to put the returned data into struct. This is what I currently have
http://pastebin.com/Vwzbeacv

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Here is how I managed.

```
class fraps
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct sFraps
    {
        public int SizeOfStruct;
        public int CurrentFPS;
        public uint TotalFrames;
        public uint TimeOfLastFrame;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
        public char[] GameName;

    };

    [DllImport("FRAPS32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FrapsSharedData();

    public int fpsGet() {
        try
        {
            sFraps fps = (sFraps)Marshal.PtrToStructure(FrapsSharedData(), typeof(sFraps));
            return fps.CurrentFPS;
        }
        catch
        {
            return -1;
        }


    }
}
```

And at the top you need to

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Using unmanaged DLLs in C# code is far more complicated then I initially thought. One thing I don't understand, how do we figure out the stuct's structure in the first place?

Comment: The structure itself you can find in documentation and write it in C# way. Then set the function from unmanaged library it will check the struct's structure and fill it.

Comment: @NikolaiArsenov So there is no way to "discover" the structure or the dll's struct? I imagined there would be some kind of reverse engineering tool that'd show such a thing.

Comment: There is such tools, i am sure. Because most of all functionality for C# libraries are generated by tools. E.g. SharpDX project or SharpGL - generated wraps equal to DirectX and OpenGL libraries for C++.

See these articles:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668932/automatically-generate-c-sharp-wrapper-class-from-dll-in-visual-studio-2010-expr
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120690/tool-for-creating-net-wrappers-for-a-com-dll